# npx create-react-app is not creating servicework.js file in src forlder

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to learn building PWAs and have been reading about this concept for the past few days. The problem I am facing is; whenever create a new react app with the help of npx, it never creates a serviceworker.js file.

Files after creating a new react project

[image]

All the articles and the YouTube tutorials show that npx create-react-app is creating that file for them. I have tried to google this issue but I think I am the only one who is facing this problem. I assume I can create a serviceworker.js file myself but I am curious that why npx is not doing this for me. I have tried to reinstall everything, tried to update everything but nothing is helping.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install it with a pwa template:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

Then it's in the `src` folder.

Make sure you have the latest node version installed for that.